# Load csv to DB2 database

Tags: db2

I'd like to ask if my syntax is correct in loading a csv format file to a DB2 Database. I cannot confirm as I'm having problems in configuring DB2 in my local. I'd also like to confirm the placement of double quote is correct for both dateformat and timeformat?

Below is my code snippet.

```
LOGFILE=/mnt/bin/log/myLog.txt

db2 "load from /mnt/bin/test.csv of del modified by coldel noeofchar noheader dateformat=\"YYYY-MM-DD\" timeformat=\"HH:MM:SS\" usedefaults METHOD P(1,2,3,4,5) messages $LOGFILE insert_update into myuser.desctb(DESC_ID,START_DATE,START_TIME,END_DATE,END_TIME)"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `modified by coldel` then you should also specify the delimiter character. If the delimiter really is a comma, then omit the coldel option.

Additionally `insert_update` is for the [IMPORT](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008304.html) command (not for load command), but import is a logged action which reduces insert throughput. You can use `... replace into ...` with the LOAD command. Study the docs for the details.

The quoting seems OK, but correctness of the formats depends on data file values.

Refer to the [LOAD](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008305.html) documentation for details, you should study this page and the related pages.

An alternative to LOAD is to use [INGEST](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dm.doc/doc/c0057237.html) command (available in current Db2-clients) which has insert, replace, merge and other options and is high throughput (compared to import).

Comment: Hi @mao, the delimiter is comma. Should I place in the code: db2 "load from /mnt/bin/test.csv of del modified by noeofchar noheader dateformat=\"YYYY-MM-DD\" timeformat=\"HH:MM:SS\" usedefaults METHOD P(1,2,3,4,5) messages $LOGFILE insert_update into myuser.desctb(DESC_ID,START_DATE,START_TIME,END_DATE,END_TIME)" For the insert_update, I am using load for faster moving of large amount of data to the database. Is there a command which acts the same as insert_update for load?

Comment: `LOAD` can't do insert_update. You would need to `LOAD` to a staging table, then perform say a `MERGE` statement.

Comment: Also things like dateformat=\"YYYY-MM-DD\", noheader are the default, so you should not need those.   `noeofchar` is not (I believe) an option of DB2 LUW LOAD.  Seting WARNINGCOUNT is a good idea unless you want every row rejected if you get the options wrong (it takes al ooong time to do that is you have a lot of rows)

Comment: Hi @PaulVernon, I realize that I need to retain the data inside the table and cannot use LOAD REPLACE INTO as it will remove everything in the table. Would you recommend if I use IMPORT INSERT_UPDATE instead? Or is there a way that is more efficient and faster in processing the data.

Comment: `LOAD` to a staging table, then a `MERGE` would likely be the fastest. INGEST should be faster than IMPORT and can be used to do insert/update.  IMPORT is fine if your volumes are not too big